# EGit not showing changed files.

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have been using EGit to upload my stuff to github for a few months now.

But off late I do not see what files have been changed, and I dont know why. Please help.

As you can see I have updated some files and I cannot see a list of files in the files section.

[image]

Comment: without more details this question is likely going to get closed as off topic. Did anything change? Did you check the egit website for whether an update is necessary? Did you change anything else?

Comment: Yes. Everything is up to date. I haven't changed anything in the past few days. But today it just vanished. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment 2 at the [Eclipse bug 446534](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446534) mentioned, calling table.pack() will solve this problem for a single tableviewer.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a problem with Mac OS X 10.10 and SWT, see [Eclipse bug 446534](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446534) for details.

Note that the heading above the table says "Files (1/1)", so EGit calculated the changed files correctly, but it isn't visible. Try if resizing the window makes it appear.

The Git Staging view, which is another way to commit using EGit doesn't seem to have the same problem. Maybe you could consider using that instead of the Commit dialog, see the [user guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Git_Staging_View).

Comment: Resizing the window helped. I usually have that problem on Ubuntu 12.04 
I am surprised to see it on my Mac now :( Thank you for your help :) You have a keen eye :D

Comment: you can also do a wildcard search for "*" and the first file will show up.